# Symfony 4 Doctrine LifecycleEventArgs getEntity() vs getObject()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

What is the difference between `LifecycleEventArgs::getObject()` and `LifecycleEventArgs::getEntity()`?

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

/**
 * Class MyListener
 *
 * @package App\EventListener
 */
class MyListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::postUpdate,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
     */
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();
        $object = $event->getObject();

        $entity === $object; //true...
    }
}
```

So far as I can tell these two methods return the exact same *object*, ie they point to the same instance of a given Entity.

Is that always the case?

Should one be used over the other or does it not matter?

Comment: For reference to the actual code: https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/blob/fdaaa50cb23760c9da2d6dcab9f10caa34d92b61/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Event/LifecycleEventArgs.php#L35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The `getObject()` method comes from the parent class of the `LifecycleEventArgs` class which is provided by the `doctrine/persistence` package.

The base event class is mainly helpful when you want to build an integration layer for several Doctrine implementations (e.g. ORM and ODM) and in which case you would use `getObject()`.